# Release the acquired lock after specific timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, locking

I'm trying to release a `lock` after some timeout. The `lock` is acquired to do any database changes so that multiple requests will not update the database simultaneously.

Below is the code

```
public static readonly _lockObject = new Object();

public bool UpdateData(ModifiedData modifiedData)
{
    var success = false;
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(()=>
        {
            try
            {
                SessionManager.Instance.OpenConversation(true); // Starts a session using nHibernate
                //Modifications

                success = true;
                SessionManager.Instance.EndConversation(true);

            }
            catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
                //Do I need to handle any condition here
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
        if (!thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))  // Timeout
        {
           if (!success)
              thread.Abort();
           else
           {
             thread.Join();
           }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!success)
             {
                    throw new Exception("Should Not occur");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

are there any better approaches available?? I tried with `Action.BeginInvoke` but in that not able to kill or stop action execution after some timeout.

Comment: This is not even a static method.  It would do nothing to stop two or more users from making simultaneous requests.   Not sure about your modifications but Command has a timeout option.

Comment: Should "_The `lock` is acquired_" actually read "_The lock is **required**_"?

Comment: indeed it's a static method I forgot to add.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you shouldn't make your lock object public if it's for internal working of the class.  Typically they are marked as private.

The lock statement is just wrapper around the [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  The Monitor class has a built in [timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270858(v=vs.110).aspx).   To use it we need to write a bit more code but less than what you currently have

```
private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();

public bool UpdateData()
{
    bool lockWasTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ref lockWasTaken);
        if (lockWasTaken)
        {
            // do work here
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockWasTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
        }
    }

    return lockWasTaken;
}
```

Also if you are going to throw an exception you should make it useful and shouldn't normally use the standard Exception class.  If it's timing out then throw the [TimeoutException](http://TimeoutException).  This make it easier for callers to know it timed out and they can decide if they can capture it and retry.

Comment: Actually, other threads need to wait until the thread which has taken the lock either completes or we need to explicitly stop the thread from further execution. It's not new threads should be sent false.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Then using Monitor but with _Wait_ & _Pulse_ methods plus setting timeout in nHibernate should achieve what you want.